# Performance profiling with Graphite

Tags: spring, performance, profiling, dropwizard, graphite

Is it possible to perform profiling on the `graphite` metrics? 
e.g. - Let's say my publicly exposed service invokes another REST api and performs some DB operation before returning the response back to consumer... is it possible to understand/identify from the metrics that my service has taken `x secs` to respond, *out-of-which* `y secs` has been for the REST api interaction and `z secs` for DB interaction etc... 
As I understand I can always generate metrics *individually* for my service call, inner REST api invocation and DB interaction that gives me x, y and z respectively. What I am trying to figure out, if/how we can find co-relation between x, y and z using `graphite`.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have individual metrics for every stage that you want to monitor independently.

But actually I would recommend different approach like JAMon ( http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) that basically will act as you want out of the box (of course with configured log4j).